# Organizing a large list of notifications in a block on the dashboard

Tags: web, notification, dashboard

[image]We are working on a dashboard for a bank and it is turning out to be quite loaded with information. In one of the blocks we provide information about the client base (how many clients you currently have, which ones have opened accounts, which ones haven’t yet, etc.)

And under this information we want to give small messages about what is happening with the client base: with whom we have not communicated for a long time, whose deposit has been closed, who is withdrawing money, etc.

The problem is that there can be a lot of such messages, and we cannot combine them together in groups for technical reasons.

Maybe you've come across best practices on how to implement this?